# Get static ipv6 ip

Tags: linux, ipv6

I'm trying to get an IPv6 IP for my wireless interface. When getting an IPv4 I see this:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:00:bf:29:b2  
          inet addr:192.168.1.128  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:ff:febf:29b2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:47 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:723 (723.0 B)  TX bytes:12641 (12.6 KB)
```

Now I'm trying to get an IPv6 IP:

```
$ sudo ifconfig wlan0 inet6 add fe80::215:ff:febf:29b::1
```

And I get this error:

```
fe80::215:ff:febf:29b::1: Resolver Error 0 (no error)
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use :: only once. To cite the standard:

*"The longest sequence of consecutive all-zero fields is replaced by double-colon. If there are multiple longest runs of all-zero fields, then it is the leftmost that is compressed. E.g., 2001:db8:0:0:1:0:0:1 is rendered as 2001:db8::1:0:0:1 rather than as 2001:db8:0:0:1::1."*

Try instead: `sudo ifconfig wlan0 inet6 add fe80::215:ff:febf:29b1`